# Not able to convert promises array to observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, angular5

**EDIT:**
Added Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/oiSHJxomTILEFLWUC0Y5

I am getting following error when I am trying to use concatAll to convert a higher-order Observable into a first-order Observable by concatenating the inner Observables in order.

**Error:**

```
ERROR TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.from(...).concatAll is not a function
```

**service.ts:**

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { WebWorkerService } from 'angular2-web-worker';


constructor(private _webWorkerService: WebWorkerService) {}


public computeFactorials(firstFactorial: number, numberOfFactorials: number): Observable < number > {
    let promises: Promise < number > [] = [];
    for (let i = firstFactorial; i < firstFactorial + numberOfFactorials; i++) {
        const p: Promise < number > = this._webWorkerService.run(this.fact, i);
        promises.push(p);
    }

    return Observable.from(promises.map((promise) => {
        return Observable.from(promise);
    })).concatAll();
}

public fact(x) {
    try {
        if (x == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (x < 0) {
            return undefined;
        }
        for (var i = x; --i;) {
            x *= i;
        }
        return x;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("e ", e);
    }
}
```

**component.ts:**

```
public computeFactorials() {
    this.factorialService.computeFactorials(this.firstFactorial, this.numberOfFactorials)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {

      }, (err) => {

      });
  }
```

What is wrong with above code, am I missing any import statement? Is there any better way to convert promises array to observable?

Comment: should not it be `return Observable.fromPromise(...)`

Comment: Did you import the concatAll method somewhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import any operator you want to use in your application:

So try the following in you server.ts file:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatAll';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to accomplish, let know if I am right!
[live example](https://plnkr.co/edit/fMwX7GSrff9BSqfeEFDE?p=preview)

You could use `Promise.all` to resolve when all the orders has been resolve, then transforming to `Observable` and finally use `concatAll` to merge the resolved values.

```
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/from';
import { concatAll } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

public computeFactorials(
  firstFactorial: number, 
  numberOfFactorials: number): Observable<number> {
    const promises: Promise<number> [] = [];
    for (let i = firstFactorial; i < firstFactorial + numberOfFactorials; i++) {
      const p: Promise<number> = this.asyncFunction(i);
      promises.push(p);
    }

    return fromPromise(Promise.all(promises)).pipe(concatAll());
}
```

Comment: Your method returns Observable<Observable<number>>, not Observable<number>. You need to flatten your result to get Observable<number>, either with merge (if the order is not important) or concat (if the order is important - as in this case).

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Now I came up another approached, thanks a lot.